# How to subtract two dates in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying  to find how long did it take for each order to be shipped out.  Provide the `ordID`, customer `name`, and `days_to_ship` for each order.  List them from the longest delay (between order date and ship date) to the shortest.

```
SELECT OrdID, name, (ShipDate-orderDate) AS Days_to_Ship
    FROM ORDERS, CUSTOMERS
    WHERE ShipDate-OrderDate=(select Max(ShipDate-OrderDate) from orders)
    ORDER BY Days_to_Ship DESC;
```

Comment: you can simply order by the difference in the dates, and the largest difference (the longest delay) will be the first row; unless I misunderstood your question. Also, please clarify which database you are using as date functions vary between database systems.

Comment: I'm trying to find how long dose it take to shipped the product out from the order date to the shipping date. Then order them from the longest wait time to the shortest waiting time.

Comment: Which Sql please (MySql, Oracle, SqlServer etc)?

Comment: It in Microsoft MSQL server.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
OrdID,name,DATEDIFF(ShipDate,OrderDATE) as Days_to_Ship
from ORDERS, CUSTOMERS    
order by DATEDIFF(ShipDate,OrderDATE) desc;
```

Comment: Think this might be better as a comment, but that's up to @timus2001

Comment: do I write that on the select line or the where line?

Comment: if you need to  show the delays then in select line , if you need to sort by delays then in where line

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified which RDBMS, but you can use `DATEDIFF` in [MySql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) and [SqlServer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx) (slightly different implementations). MySql's `DateDiff` returns the difference in days:

```
select o.OrdID, c.Name, DATEDIFF(o.ShipDate, o.OrderDate) as Days_to_Ship
from ORDERS o 
   INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS c on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
order by Days_to_Ship desc;
```

For Sql Server you need to specify the interval to `DateDiff`, and switch the dates around:

```
select o.OrdID, c.Name, DATEDIFF(dd, o.OrderDate, o.ShipDate) as Days_to_Ship
from ORDERS o 
   INNER JOIN CUSTOMERS c on o.CustomerId = c.CustomerId 
order by Days_to_Ship desc;
```

I've assumed a join condition between `Customers` and `Orders`.

If you just need the longest delay, restrict the list with `LIMIT 1` (MySql) or `TOP 1` (Sql Server) - together with `Order By`, you don't need to evaluate a `WHERE MAX` at all.

Comment: It work but some of it are showing negative number. The Date is be YYYY/mm/dd.

Comment: *"Negative would mean that the order shipped before it was ordered"* Or that you have the arguments in the wrong order.

Comment: well the date is write as Year/Month/day.

Comment: @user3370044 As per Mike's comment, I made an error - the parameters to SqlServer DateDiff is different to MySql - I got the SqlServer one wrong - just switch order date and shipping date in the DateDiff.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function `DATEDIFF`

```
DATEDIFF(dd, dateTimeField1, dateTimeField2)
```

where `dd` is used to get difference in terms of days. you can use others too.

like

> ```
> datepart       Abbreviation
> year           yy, yyyy
> quarter        qq, q
> month          mm, m
> dayofyear      dy, y
> day            dd, d
> week           wk, ww
> weekday        dw, w
> hour           hh
> minute         mi, n
> second         ss, s
> millisecond    ms
> microsecond    mcs
> nanosecond     ns
> ```

Comment: `DATEDIFF` also accepts readable interval names such as "day". No need to be obfuscatory.